# matlab: putting a circled number onto a graph

Tags: matlab, annotations, graphing

I want to put a circled number on a graph as a marker *near* (but not on) a point. Sounds easy, but I also want to be invariant of zoom/aspect ratio changes.

Because of this invariant, I can't draw a circle as a line object (without redrawing it upon rescale); if I use a circle marker, I'd have to adjust its offset upon rescale.

The simplest approach I can think of is to use the Unicode or Wingdings characters ① ② ③ etc. in a string for the `text()` function. But unicode doesn't seem to work right, and the following sample only works with ① and not for the other numbers (which yield rectangle boxes):

works:

```
clf; text(0.5,0.5,char(129),'FontName','WingDings')
```

doesn't work (should be a circled 2):

```
clf; text(0.5,0.5,char(130),'FontName','WingDings')
```

What gives, and can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work for me, uses Matlab's latex interpreter, and `\textcircled`:

```
clf; text(0.5, 0.5, '$\textcircled{2}$', 'Interpreter', 'latex')
```

The `\textcircled` command seems have some [offset problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers), maybe you can try to improve the used latex command and let us know :)

Following the above link, for example, I get better results with:

```
clf; text(0.5, 0.5, '$\raisebox{.5pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt} {2}}}$', 'Interpreter', 'latex')
```

Still, two digit numbers look awful.

Comment: sweet!!!!!!! That really helps. Thank you -- I know a few basics in TeX but haven't been using it much for the last 10 years; I stopped using it once I figured out it was taking too much of my brain cells to be familiar with a tool I don't use that often. :-(

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example where the markers (text+circles) are invariant to zoom/resize:

```
%# some graph in 2D
[adj,XY] = bucky;
N = 30;
adj = adj(1:N,1:N);
XY = XY(1:N,1:2);

%# plot edges
[xx yy] = gplot(adj, XY);
hFig = figure(); axis equal
line(xx, yy, 'LineStyle','-', 'Color','b', 'Marker','s', 'MarkerFaceColor','g')

%# draw text near vertices
xoff = 0; yoff = 0;     %# optional offsets
str = strtrim(cellstr(num2str((1:N)')));
hTxt = text(XY(:,1)+xoff, XY(:,2)+yoff, str, ...
    'FontSize',12, 'FontWeight','bold', ...
    'HorizontalAlign','right', 'VerticalAlign','bottom');

%# draw circles around text
e = cell2mat(get(hTxt, {'Extent'}));
p = e(:,1:2) + e(:,3:4)./2;
hLine = line('XData',p(:,1), 'YData',p(:,2), ...
    'LineStyle','none', 'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',18, ...
    'MarkerFaceColor','none', 'MarkerEdgeColor','k');

%# link circles position to text (on zoom and figure resize)
callbackFcn = @(o,e) set(hLine, ...
    'XData',cellfun(@(x)x(1)+x(3)/2,get(hTxt,{'Extent'})), ...
    'YData',cellfun(@(x)x(2)+x(4)/2,get(hTxt,{'Extent'})) );
set(zoom(hFig), 'ActionPostCallback',callbackFcn)
set(hFig, 'ResizeFcn',callbackFcn)
```

[image: screenshot]

Compare against the LaTeX-based solution that [@catchmeifyoutry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10818610/97160) proposed (pay attention to the two-digits numbers):

```
%# use LaTeX to draw circled text at vertices
%#str = num2str((1:N)', '$\\textcircled{%d}$');
str = num2str((1:N)', '$\\raisebox{.5pt}{\\textcircled{\\raisebox{-.9pt} {%d}}}$');
text(XY(:,1), XY(:,2), str, ...
    'HorizontalAlign','right', 'VerticalAlign','bottom', ...
    'Interpreter','latex', 'FontSize',18)
```

[image: screenshot_latex]

Comment: ooh, interesting! I'll have to try this out when I get a chance.