# Connecting the dots in an image

Tags: matlab, plot, connect

I have the following image:

[image]

Is there a way to connect the dots (draw a line between them) using `MATLAB`? I tried `plot` by passing it the image, but didn't work.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The way I'm expecting to connect the dots is roughly as shown through the red line in the image sample below:

[image]

Comment: You may consider checking [@Amro's answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818392/matlab-putting-a-circled-number-onto-a-graph). Btw, I think the image will get quite confusing with the dots connected hahaha…

Comment: If you can grab the (x,y) coords of the dots off the image using some image processing, then you can connect them nicely with a Delaunay triangulation.

Comment: Connect the dots sounds a little ambiguous. Could you clarify: do you want to plot a triangulated mesh as @Dan suggests or plot points in sequential order as a plot command on sorted data would?

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of ways you can do this, for instance as follows:

```
img=im2double(imread('SWal5.png'));
m = bwmorph(~img,'shrink',Inf);
[ix iy]  = find(m); 
tri = delaunay(iy,ix);

image(img)
hold on
triplot(tri,iy,ix,'g')
set(gca,'Ydir','reverse')
axis square off
```

[image]

If instead you want something akin to a `plot`, then you can try this after running  the `find` step:

```
[ix ii]=sort(ix);
iy = iy(ii);

imshow(img)
hold on
plot(iy,ix,'k')
set(gca,'Ydir','reverse')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For the first portion of code, I got the following error: `Error using delaunay
At least three input points must be provided to define a
triangular mesh.`

Comment: @Simplicity could be an issue with the image datatype. I substituted the to `double` conversion with a `im2double` statement.

Comment: The image data type is actually `double`. I didn't really understand the error.

Comment: @Simplicity the error appears to have something to do with the `ix` and `iy` arrays, these should be column vectors with more than 3 elements. Check that this is so...

Comment: When I ran your code as embedded with my code I got this error. But, when stand alone it seems to work. It seems that the result connects all the points together. Cannot we get the result as like in a drawing book where we just walk along with points? This is what I'm actually looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Simplicity could you post an image as an example of what you want as output?

Answer (score 1):

To plot a trail through a number of points,  you could define an adjacency matrix and use [gplot](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/gplot.html) to display.

Here's a snippet to show the idea, although you'll note that with this rather simple code the output is a bit messy. It depends how clean a line you want and if crossovers are allowed - there are probably better ways of creating the adjacency matrix.

This assumes you've extracted the position of your points into a matrix "data" which is size n x 2 (in this case, I just took 200 points out of your image to test).

Basically, the nearest points are found with [knnsearch](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/knnsearch.html) (requires Statistics toolbox), and then the adjacency matrix is filled in by picking a starting point and determining the nearest neighbour not yet used. This results in every point being connected to at maximum two other points, providing that the number of points found with knnsearch is sufficient that you never back yourself into a corner where all the nearest points (100 in this case) have already been used.

---

```
datal = length(data);
marked = ones(datal,1);
m = 100; % starting point - can be varied
marked(m)=0; % starting point marked as 'used'

adj = zeros(datal); 
IDX = knnsearch(data, data,'K',100); 

for n = 1:datal;
    x = find(marked(IDX(m,:))==1,1,'first'); % nearest unused neighbour
    adj(m,IDX(m,x))=1; % two points marked as connected in adj
    marked(IDX(m,x))=0; % point marked as used
    m = IDX(m,x); 
end

gplot(adj, data); hold on; plot(data(:,1),data(:,2),'rx');
```

[image: gplot with m = 100]